# Center aligned selection with animation in ListView (?)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I need a component that works like the picture below but I'm having trouble coming up with some kind of decent solution that works.

I want the list to have a center locked selection but being scrollable with the d-pad. This is for an application running on a TV so no need for touch scroll. So when pressing down on the remote d-pad the list will scroll and a new item will size up and the current selected one will size down and the new selection will still be in the middle.

[image: This is what I'm looking for]

I've tried doing this using a ListView that I extended and programmatically scrolling when pressing down or up. On scroll finished I called notifyDatasetChanged() on the ListView for re-inflating of the childs and in the ListViews adapters getView() I made the animation of the view located at the current selected position.

This is not optimal since I need to call notifyDatasetChanged(), which re-inflates all visible views, for the animation to apply. The UI becomes laggy when doing this and scrolling fast. It's also not possible to make som kind of compress animation when current selected item goes out of selection. There is also some trouble with the end items (read views) such the first or last in the list when doing animation of them, the may sometimes go out of screen.

I think that his must have been done before and maybe I'm missing it when searching for an answer.

**Have anyone done something similar or do you have some suggestions of how this can be achieved? Maybe I'm just starting of with the wrong component here..**

Regards,
Kristoffer

Comment: Interesting idea. I'd start with a RecyclerView as the base view.  Will post an example in a bit.

Comment: Great simon and thanks for the idea. Looking forward to see what you'll come up with.

Comment: Use RecyclerView instead of ListView,
Look this link [http://stackoverflow.com/a/43083576/5887320](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43083576/5887320)

Comment: Yea, 100% RecyclerView usage today. This is a 3 year old thread ;)